# How can I use inner module outputs without increasing model size

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm gonna keep my explanation short, since I have lots of code to present.

I am trying to develop a new autoencoder architecture, but I am having trouble managing the forward/backward pass size of my model. I'm gonna explain with these test codes:

Imagine we have the two following modules. one returns only the output while the other returns an extra inner output.

```
class testNet1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_in=3, dim_inner=5, dim_out=3):
        super().__init__()
        self.tube1 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube3 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube4 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube2 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)

        self.conv_out = nn.Conv2d(dim_inner*4, dim_out, 3, 1, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.tube1(x)
        x2 = self.tube1(x)
        x3 = self.tube1(x)
        x4 = self.tube1(x)

        x = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3, x4), dim=1)
        x = self.conv_out(x)
        return x, x1
    

class testNet2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_in=3, dim_inner=5, dim_out=3):
        super().__init__()
        self.tube1 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube3 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube4 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)
        self.tube2 = nn.Conv2d(dim_in, dim_inner, 3, 1, 1)

        self.conv_out = nn.Conv2d(dim_inner*4, dim_out, 3, 1, 1)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.tube1(x)
        x2 = self.tube1(x)
        x3 = self.tube1(x)
        x4 = self.tube1(x)

        x = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3, x4), dim=1)
        x = self.conv_out(x)
        return x
```

These two modules have the exact same number of parameters, the exact same forward/backward pass size (0.04MB) which you can check for yourself using the `torchsummary` library.

Now, I made these two models, where one uses the testNet1 and the other uses testNet2. in these examples I haven't used the inner outputs. But according to my tests, using them or not, doesn't really affect the F/B pass size.

```
class testModule1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.net1_1 = testNet1()
        self.net1_2 = testNet1()
        self.net1_3 = testNet1()

    def forward(self, x):
        x, y = self.net1_1(x)
        x, z = self.net1_1(x)
        x, w = self.net1_1(x)
        return x
    

class testModule2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.net2_1 = testNet2()
        self.net2_2 = testNet2()
        self.net2_3 = testNet2()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.net2_1(x)
        x = self.net2_1(x)
        x = self.net2_1(x)
        return x
```

Now these two models have much much different F/B pass sizes. for an arbitrary input size of (3, 64, 64), the module with inner outputs (`testModule1`) has a F/B pass size of 5.7GB while the second one (`testModule2`) has a size of 2.44MB.

I have tried detaching the inner output before returning it in hopes of somehow improving the size situation which obviously didn't help at all.

I want to know how would it be possible to use the inner outputs of a small module in a bigger network without increasing the model size so drastically. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.